# Why my strings can't be sorted like i want when i insert values from textview?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sorting, textview

i have counter which count how many times i click a button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            counter++;
             text.setText("Score"+counter);



        }
```

then i insert to my DB this values

```
     text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                final String Score = text.getText().toString();
                mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

                mySQLiteAdapter.insert("sccore="Score);

                mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

this is my insert function

```
public long insert(String content){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}
```

So counter values which were inserted was-> Score = 2 ,Score = 1 ,Score = 111, Score = 3, Score = 21 <--(its counter values)

then i want to see this scores in another texview so:

```
 mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    /*
     *  Open the same SQLite database
     *  and read all it's content.
     */
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
    String contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
    listContent.setText(contentRead);
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

my fucntion queueAll() looks like:

```
public String queueAll(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
            null, null, null, null, KEY_CONTENT+" desc");
    String result = "";

    int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT);
    for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
        result = result + cursor.getString(index_CONTENT) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

ok and in text view i saw this:

```
Score = 3  ,  Score=21 , Score=2 , Score=111, Score=1
```

but i want

```
score=111, score=21, score=3, score=2, score=1.
```

Why Order By DESC didnt sort this like i want in DESC? Why it thinks like this? Why My inserted counter values are not sorted DESC?

```
public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

//create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
    "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";
```

To be honest my column KEY_CONTENT should be NUMBER not STRING. How to change this?
When i change str to num will order by DESC work as i want ?

Comment: Thanks for a well prepared question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored your numbers as `text` so you get the alphabetical sorting order.

You can convert your numbers to `integer` when you query:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
        null, null, null, null, "CAST(" + KEY_CONTENT + " as integer) desc");
```

Comment: u are a wizzard :D. It works now.
Can u tell me how this works ? ""CAST(" + KEY_CONTENT + " as integer) desc")" what is cast ?

Comment: @user3202351 It's casting your column `Content` (which is stored as `text`) to `integer` data type. As all your records have a valid integer, it can cast without problems and then sort based on numeric value.

Comment: but what if my inserted value will be "qweq1qweqweScore=15"? It will cast what?

Comment: It will fail with an error as it won't be able to cast.

Comment: Good to know.. Thanks anywayfor help.